Issue with CORS when testing locally with API gateway. (AWS)
Access to fetch at 'invoke url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
I am currently having an issue with CORS working with my fetch requests to my API gateway.
I went through all the methods and made sure to allow the correct headers with the URL path parameters on each method. Also included the correct CORS information in my frontend and backend.
Anyone have any ideas?
Im expecting to be able to upload my file to an S3 bucket on the backend through API gateway and Lambda.

Made sure I have the correct URL path parameters in method request and integration requests.

included CORS in my frontend and backend code.



does not have HTTP ok status Start here.  What was the status returned by the server?  Check the response body as well.  What is supposed to be handling CORS, API Gateway or your application code?

I got a 403 forbidden and API gateway is supposed to be handling CORS but i made sue to include in my application code to be able to handle CORS also.

Heres some info from the error itself....
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Also here are the response headers...
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods Your CORS configuration only allows OPTIONS.  It's not immediately clear what actual verb you're using, but it's probably POST
